Mathematical method behind ST_Volume
For a university work, I need to know what is the mathematical method behind the st_volume function.
Does it use complex numerical integration, Monte-Carlo method or anything else?

PostGIS is open-source. Why not just review the code yourself?

Volumetric geometric algebra is backed by (SF)CGAL - here is the core librarys entry point for volume calculatons. Have fun!
